# AO Compiler: weaving process

Tags: compiler-construction, aop

I'm doing a presentation about Aspect Oriented Software Development. One of my subtopics is "AO Compiler: weaving process".
I found nothing about it on the internet. Does anybody have some information about this Compiler? I really don't know what to write about it.
(I don't want you to do my work, I just need some help at the beginning!)

Here is a similiar question: [AspectJ Weaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066327/aspectj-weaving), but unfortunalety it doesn't have any answers yet.

Comment: Never heard of it. 121,000 hits in google for this string though ,aspect oriented compiler weaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this: [Aspect Weaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_weaver).

Answer (score 1):

With PostSharp (http://www.sharpcrafters.com), an AOP tool for .NET, the "weaving" process is what happens after the compile step to weave in the aspect code.  I assume other post-compile AOP tools work in a similar way (for Java and .NET).

There are other ways to use AOP besides using a post-compiler: a dynamic runtime proxy, e.g. Castle DynamicProxy (http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx).